# asio::io_service is ending immediately with work

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, boost-asio

I'm trying to learn io_service and work with shared pointers. I want the code to work infinitely until I call stop method or sth like this. Unfortunately after seeing workHandler's output on the screen the program shutdowns. Can anybody explain why this happen?

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class Service : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Service> {
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> _service;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> _work;
    std::vector<std::thread> _threads;
    std::atomic<bool> _started{false};

public:
    Service() 
    : _service(std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>()),
    _work(std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(*_service))
    {}

    void start() { 
        auto self(this->shared_from_this());
        auto startHandler = [this, self]() {
            std::cout << "StartHandler\n";
            while(!_started) _service->run();
        };

        _threads.emplace_back(std::thread(startHandler));
    }

    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>& get() { return _service; }
};

class Worker : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Worker> {
    std::shared_ptr<Service> _service;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> _io_service;

public:
    Worker(const std::shared_ptr<Service>& service)
    : _service(service),
    _io_service(_service->get())
    {}

    void work() {
        auto self(this->shared_from_this());
        auto workHandler = [this, self]() {
            std::cout << "WorkHandler\n";
        };

        _io_service->post(workHandler);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto ser = std::make_shared<Service>();
    ser->start();
    auto worker = std::make_shared<Worker>(ser);
    worker->work();
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058)

Comment: I have debugged the code and unfortunately I have no clue why it exits. As I understand io_service should always have sth to do thankfully to io_service::work object. Here it ends after workHandler so that's why I put my question.

Comment: The code does what you've written. You create objects then they are destroyed at the end of the scope. Why do you think it should stop before exiting? The std::thread that you never join will also help by promptly calling std::terminate.

Comment: Well the captured shared_from_this should keep it alive, @rustyx, that's probably the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into undefined behaviour.

Your handlers capture shared pointers to the Service/Work objects alright. But nothing stops `main` from exiting, which will run exit handlers and tear down global library infrastructure. This is not what you want.

The problems are caused by an over-use of shared pointers. Shared pointers are ONLY good for shared ownership. In the majority of your code there is no shared ownership (`main` owns the Service!). Simplify:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83f6a7a50318c13f)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

namespace ba = boost::asio;

class Service {
    ba::io_service _service;
    boost::optional<ba::io_service::work> _work {_service};
    std::list<std::thread> _threads;

public:
    ~Service() {
        _work.reset(); // allow service to complete
        for (auto& thread : _threads)
            if (thread.joinable())
                thread.join();
    }

    void start() { 
        _threads.emplace_back([this] {
            _service.run();
        });
    }

    ba::io_service& get() { return _service; } 
};

class Worker : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Worker> {
    ba::io_service& _io;

public:
    Worker(Service& service) : _io(service.get()) {}

    void work() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        auto workHandler = [self]() {
            std::cout << "WorkHandler " << std::endl;
        };

        _io.post(workHandler);
    }
};

int main() {
    Service ser;
    ser.start();

    std::make_shared<Worker>(ser)->work();
}
```

Prints

```
WorkHandler
```

But most importantly: doesn't invoke UB and exits cleanly through joining the threads.

Comment: Off-topic: Using 1.67+ interfaces brings some subtle changes http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b866368f9a4650f0