# pthread is not starting for class instance

Tags: asynchronous, io, pthreads, boost-asio, c++98

**NOTE: C++98**

Hi, I'm a little new to c++ and I am writing a databaes program and am attempting to start a timer using the boost::asio package using pthread. The aim of the timer is to start after sql queries have been placed inside a buffer, of which will run an execute function if nothing has been received for a period of time. I have managed to get it to compile, but it doesn't look like the pthread instance is starting.

I have called the pthread inside my getInstance method, and the boost::asio alarm has been set up accordingly. What I will show below is that by calling `io_run()` directly starts the timer falls into a loop within the alarm.

**database.h**

```c++
void *run_io(void *arg);

class Database
{
private:
    static Database *dbInstance; //= NULL;

public:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::posix_time::millisec interval;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
    pthread_t timerThread;

public:
    static Database &getInstance()
    {
        if (!dbInstance)
        {
            dbInstance = new Database();
            // pthread_create(&dbInstance->timerThread,NULL,run_io,&dbInstance->io_service);
            std::cout << " INSTANCE CREATED " << std::endl;
            pthread_create(&dbInstance->timerThread, NULL, run_io, (void *)&dbInstance->io_service);
            // pthread_join(&dbInstance->timerThread, NULL);
        }
        return *dbInstance;
    }
};
```

**database.cpp**

```c++
Database *Database::dbInstance = NULL;

Database::Database()
    : interval(2000), timer(io_service, interval) {}

Database::~Database()
{
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

void Database::setAlarm(const boost::system::error_code& /* e */)
{
    std::cout << "[TEST] WE ARE IN SET ALARM " << std::endl;
    DB_WRITE_TIME = 500;

    boost::posix_time::milliseconds interval(DB_WRITE_TIME);

    // Reschedule the timer for 1 second in the future:
    timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + interval);
    // Posts the timer event
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Database::setAlarm, this, _1));
}

int Database::buffer()
{
    // DO BUFFER STUFF

    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Database::setAlarm, this, _1));
   // io_service.run() <-- uncommenting this results in the loop
    return rc ;
}

void *run_io(void *arg)
{
    boost::asio::io_service *io_service = (boost::asio::io_service *)arg;

    io_service->run();
}
```

So I don't feel like the pthread is even starting. I tried putting a print statement in there to see if it came out, and nothing appeared in my terminal.

## ---- EDIT ----

I have made changes as per Sehe's advice, however it still does not look like I am able to call the alarm handler (`setAlarm()`). I had to slightly modify it to be compatible with the whole program, but essentially it is this (I gave the interval time a value of 5000 to give it enough time for the tests):

**database.h**

```c++
class Database
{
private:
    static boost::shared_ptr<Database> dbInstance;

private:
    typedef boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    io_service io;
    boost::scoped_ptr<io_service::work> work;
    boost::posix_time::millisec interval;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
    boost::thread timerThread;

    void run_io()
    {
        std::cout << "ENTER IO THREAD" << std::endl;
        io.run();
        std::cout << "LEAVE IO THREAD" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    static Database &getInstance()
    {
        if (!dbInstance)
        {
            std::cout << " INSTANCE CREATED " << std::endl;
            dbInstance.reset(new Database());
            dbInstance->timerThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&Database::run_io,dbInstance));
        }
        return *dbInstance;
    }

    Database(); // <-- default constructor (doesn't take any args)
    ~Database();
```

**database.cpp**

```c++
boost::shared_ptr<Database> Database::dbInstance;
static const int DB_WRITE_TIME = 5000;

Database::Database()
    : work(new io_service::work(io)), interval(5000), timer(io, interval)
{
    // std::cout << " CONSTRUCTED " << std::endl;
}

Database::~Database()
{
    // std::cout << " DESTROYED " << std::endl;
    // sqlite3_close(db);
}

void Database::setAlarm(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    std::cout << "[TEST] WE ARE IN SET ALARM - ec message = " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    executeSqlInBuffer(); // once timer expire, call the execute function

    if(!ec)
    {
        boost::posix_time::milliseconds interval(DB_WRITE_TIME);
        timer.expires_from_now(interval);
        timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Database::setAlarm, this, _1));
    }
}

void Database::teardown()
{
    // std::cout << " INSTANCE SHUTTING DOWN " << std::endl;
    timer.cancel();             // stop timer loop
    work.reset();               // allows io.run() to exit
    if(timerThread.joinable())
    {
        std::cout << " JOINED " << std::endl;
        timerThread.join();     // releasing bound of shared_ptr
    }
    else std::cout << " NOT JOINED " << std::endl;
    dbInstance.reset();         // releasing instance
}

int Database::buffer()
{
    // do buffering
    if(buffer.size() == max_size)
    {    
        executeSqlInBuffer();
    }
    std::cout << timer.expires_from_now(interval) << std::endl;
    // std::cout << " ~ BEFORE TIMER ~ " << std::endl;
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Database::setAlarm, this, _1));

    return 1;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```c++
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;        // a few pthreads in main that handle other areas of the program.
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,thread1Arg,NULL);

    pthread_t dbThread;        // my pthread for the database
    pthread_create(&dbThread,NULL,dbThreadArg,NULL);

    Database& database = Database::getInstance();
    database.teardown();

    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(dbThread,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also see here that it enters and leaves the IO thread, and creates an instance, plus the debug output for `timer.expires_from_now(interval)`:

```c++
 INSTANCE CREATED 

 JOINED 
ENTER IO THREAD
LEAVE IO THREAD
...
...
0 ---> first cycle
1 ---> second cycle
...
1 ---> nth cycle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very ccnfused why anyone who uses Boost or C++11 (or both...) would ever use raw `pthread` threads (see e.g. [C++ boost asynchronous timer to run in parallel with program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334533/c-boost-asynchronous-timer-to-run-in-parallel-with-program/61355296#61355296) for a good juxtaposition).

The real problem is likely that you have `io_service` running out of *work* (see e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html).

If you have no pending async operations the thread just exits.

Another problem is accuracy issues with

```
timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + interval);
```

It's possible that some handlers take so much time that by the time you schedule your next alarm, the deadline has already expired. It's probably better to use

```
timer.expires_from_now(interval);
```

> Note this also matches the comment better. The comment suffers from comment already because it says "1 second" but it is actually some defined constant `DB_WRITE_TIME`

or separate your timer from the other handlers in some other way to guarantee accurate scheduling.

Finally, you had [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to the absense of any shutdown. The static instance never gets destroyed, but what's worth the non-detached thread never is joined, creating undefined behaviour at shutdown.

> This problem is actually almost identical to the one recently discussed here, where I also explains the way `work` guards work in more detail: [asio::io_service is ending immediately with work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430330/asioio-service-is-ending-immediately-with-work/61433004#61433004)

<strike>Here's a c++11 rewrite with the necessary fix:</strike>

Since I now noticed you're that person stuck in c++03 land for some weird reason, a Boost Thread version:

### C++03 DEMO/Boost Thread

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf129eeb7e738165)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

static const int DB_WRITE_TIME = 500;

class Database
{
  private:
    static boost::shared_ptr<Database> dbInstance;

    Database()
        : work(new io_service::work(io)),
          interval(750),
          timer(io, interval)
    {
        std::cout << "INSTANCE CREATED" << std::endl;
    }

    void on_timer_completed(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
        std::cout << "[on_timer_completed] " << ec.message() << std::endl;

        if (!ec) {
            boost::posix_time::milliseconds interval(DB_WRITE_TIME);

            // Reschedule the timer
            timer.expires_from_now(interval);
            timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Database::on_timer_completed, this, _1));
        }
    }

    int buffer()
    {
        // DO BUFFER STUFF

        timer.expires_from_now(interval);
        timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Database::on_timer_completed, this, _1));
        // io_service.run() <-- uncommenting this results in the loop
        return 1; // rc ;
    }

  public:
    void do_stuff() {
        buffer(); // whatever it does
    }

    void teardown() {
        std::cout << "INSTANCE SHUTTING DOWN\n";
        timer.cancel(); // stop timer loop
        work.reset();   // allows io.run() to exit
        if (timerThread.joinable()) {
            timerThread.join(); // releasing the bound shared_ptr
        }
        dbInstance.reset(); // releasing the instance
    }

    ~Database() {
        //sqlite3_close(db);
        std::cout << "INSTANCE DESTROYED\n";
    }

  private:
    typedef boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    io_service io;
    boost::scoped_ptr<io_service::work> work;
    boost::posix_time::millisec interval;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
    boost::thread timerThread;

    void run_io() {
        std::cout << "ENTER IO THREAD" << std::endl;
        io.run();
        std::cout << "LEAVE IO THREAD" << std::endl;
    }
public:
    static Database &getInstance()
    {
        if (!dbInstance)
        {
            dbInstance.reset(new Database());
            dbInstance->timerThread =
                boost::thread(boost::bind(&Database::run_io, dbInstance));
        }
        return *dbInstance;
    }
};

boost::shared_ptr<Database> Database::dbInstance;

int main() {
    Database& db = Database::getInstance();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));

    db.do_stuff();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(3));
    // ....

    db.teardown();
}
```

Prints

```
INSTANCE CREATED
ENTER IO THREAD
[on_timer_completed] Success
[on_timer_completed] Success
[on_timer_completed] Success
[on_timer_completed] Success
[on_timer_completed] Success
INSTANCE SHUTTING DOWN
[on_timer_completed] Operation canceled
LEAVE IO THREAD
INSTANCE DESTROYED
```

Comment: hey Sehe, thanks a lot for that explanation. I have made the changes you have recommended, however it still doesn't look like the alarm handler is being called for some reason. I put in some debug prints, and saw that the return for `timer.expires_from_now(interval)` starts at `0` and then loops as `1` for the entire program, not calling the alarm handler.